# Running a Sitecore Powershell script from code

Tags: c#, powershell, sitecore

I have installed the popular [Powershell Console](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) Sitecore plugin, and so far I'm loving it.

I would like to be able to invoke a specific script programmatically in C# (as in, as a consequence of user input), but I could not find any valid resource pointing me in the right direction.

Is there any way of achieving this? Do the rules for classic Powershell scripts apply to the Sitecore version?

Comment: Be sure to check out http://sitecore.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm also curious what you are building. Perhaps it could be completely built in SPE. There are rules you can apply to scripts and script libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can directly call any PowerShell script from your own code using the following

```cs
using Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Host;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class TestSPE
    {
        public void Invoke()
        {
            using (ScriptSession scriptSession = ScriptSessionManager.NewSession("Default", true))
            {
                Item speScriptItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/path-or-id/to-spe-item");
                string script = speScriptItem["Script"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(script))
                    scriptSession.ExecuteScriptPart(script);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to add a reference to `Cognifide.PowerShell.dll` in your project.

If your script is not stored on a `PowerShell Script` item in Sitecore then you pass in a string with the SPE commands and script you wish to run.

You can read more in this blog post about [Using PowerShell Console for Sitecore in Your Own Code](http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2012/04/06/using-powershell-console-for-sitecore-in-your-own-code/)

**Update:**

To create a "script item", create an item using Template from:

```
/sitecore/templates/Modules/PowerShell Console/PowerShell Script
```

This will provide you `Script body` where you can put your code. You can find examples of the default SPE scripts in the modules Script Library under `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library`.

**Update 2:**

To get return values from the script, you call to pass `false` for the `stringOutput` parameter on the method:

```cs
List<object> results; 
results = scriptSession.ExecuteScriptPart(script, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this later!

Comment: How do I save a script as a "script item"?

Comment: Thanks. I'm off soon and I'll be on holiday for a week, but I will definitely try your answer when I get back!

Comment: I would LOVE to try your solution, but incredibly enough my Project seems unable to reference the Cognifide.PowerShell.dll - Intellisense grabs it just right, but compile always fails claiming that it cannot find the namespace "Cognified" (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Even the Object browser can see it, but at compile time always fails. My Project is targeting .Net Framework 4.5. Any hints?

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi Answer updated with namespaces, it has changed from the original article so it may be why it is complaining (I always use Resharper so don't always look at them!)

Comment: I am using the correct namespaces, which works fine while writing the code (and I can navigate to them in the Object Browser). However, Visual Studio becomes unable to resolve the reference when I build the Project and complain about a non-existing "missing reference". This is highly unusual, and frustrating.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I misunderstood. SPE 4.1 is built using .Net Framework 4.5.2, so you'll need to change target framework of your project (or possibly older versions of SPE were build with 4.5, not sure)

Comment: It's for backwards compatibility reasons. SC 8.2 requires 4.5.2 minimum, and so the module has been compiled with the same to support it. It's fine if you're using as-is, but if your code references it then you need to be on the same version (or newer).

Comment: I could only fix this by upgrading my project to 4.6 - no old version of the .dll seemed to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126922/discussion-between-emanuele-ciriachi-and-jammykam).